# IBM JDK dumps too many heaps per OutOfMemory. How can I decrease this #?

Tags: jvm, ibm-jvm

We're new to the IBM jvm. When reviewing heap dumps caused by OutOfMemoryError (i..e -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError), we see often multiple dumps (.phd files) generated in the same instant. Example:

heapdump.20141111.011601.8944.0003.phd
heapdump.20141111.011601.8944.0005.phd
heapdump.20141111.011601.8944.0007.phd
heapdump.20141111.011601.8944.0009.phd

As I read these, the jvm generated these 4 heap dumps at 2014-11-11 01:16:01 am, for pid #8944.

So why 4? And Why 4 in the same second? [I assumed because 4 actually OOM's occurred in the same second]

reviewing these dump, I  found them to be pretty identical. Dumps 2,3, and 4 don't add any info, but only clutter and fill up the drive.

How can I configure the IBM jvm to dump only one heap dump? Can I configure a 'wait time' between heap dumps?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not 100%sure about the cause of the multiple dump, could be that the dump/recovery process is generating another OOM.

You can use the IBM JDK [-Xdump](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21242497) option (controls the way you use dump agents and dumps) to limit the number of dumps you get on `OutOfMemoryErrors` by providing a [range](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21242497#Limiting_Dumps_Using_Filters).
For example, to limit the number to a single dump use a range of 0..1: `-Xdump:heap:range=0..1`
The default range is `1..4`, you can see it by running the JVM with `-Xdump:what`